# Not able to get bot response in discord using asyn functions. Unable to figure out what is wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, google-sheets-api

I am here using googlesheet v4 api as backend for my discord bot. My discord bot goes there to check if a value is matching or not. If it is matching the bot will reply the user with a message and if not then also the bot will reply the user. I am unable to get any response from bot. Remember my code is running from async/await functions. I have even removed message.author.bot to check if the bot is causing any issue. Here is my code.

```
client.on('message',(message)=>{
    
        if(message.author.bot) return;
        if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)){
            const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = message.content.trim().substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
            console.log(CMD_NAME);
            console.log(args);
            const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('SheetId');
//Sheet id has been removed to have anonymity for the spreedsheet

            accessSheet(creds,doc,args).then(()=>{
            
              if(sheetarr[1]=="YES"){
                client.on('message',(message)=>{
    
                    if(message.author.bot) return;
                    message.reply("Can you please verify your email in private message?");
                });
              
              }else if(sheetarr[1]=="NO"){
                client.on('message',(message)=>{
                    if(message.author.bot) return;
                    message.reply("Admission to this batch has been closed! Please try admission in another batch or contact outscal team");
                });
                
              }
            });
              
            }
            
               
});




async function accessSheet(creds,doc,args){
    
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
    await doc.loadInfo();
    const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[1];
    const rows = await sheet.getRows({
        
    });

    let RowCounter = sheet.rowCount;
    console.log(RowCounter);
    console.log(rows[0].Clan);
    var argument = args;
    
    for(let i=0;i<100;i++){
        if(argument == rows[i].Clan){
            sheetarr[0]=rows[i].SheetId;
            sheetarr[1] = rows[i].Enabled;
            sheetarr[2]= rows[i].RoleId;
            
            return 0;
           }
    }

    
}
```

Unable to figure out why the code is not working. Newbie here any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is `message.author.bot` always true?

Comment: I have even removed it but even then it won't work! @DaniR Thank you for your time though.

Comment: Note that `client.on` is the syntax for **adding an event listener** and not **replying to a message**. Your code sets a message listener, then when some criteria are met, sets additional message listeners.

Comment: @tehhowch in this situation what should I use then? I have even seen github cheat sheet for discord js and can't find one reference which can make it work? https://gist.github.com/koad/316b265a91d933fd1b62dddfcc3ff584 what would you suggest to try? Thank you for your time!

Comment: You shouldn't be nesting message events, infact there should never be more than 1. One event should handle all possible commands. Otherwise you will get memory leaks down the line.

Comment: @Elitezen thank you for this suggestion and pointing out bad practice! Will improve my code!